# Show sheet/tab name in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have inserted the following function in a cell, but all I am getting is: #NAME.

```
=RIGHT(CELL("filename";A1);LEN(CELL("filename";A1))-FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1);1))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably simpler to use this version: `=REPLACE(CELL("filename";A1);1;FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1));"")`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed was that you use semicolons instead of commas. I'm not sure if this is because of how you have your preferences set, but I had to replace every semicolon with a comma before I could proceed.

Once I did, though, your formula worked fine.

The only other thing I can think of is...have you tried saving the file?

From the help for `Cell`:

> Returns empty text ("") if the worksheet that contains reference has not yet been saved.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks like I have made a simple error. The interface language was not English! It was late that night.